# Interpolation Result

Tags: functional-analysis

I have read in a paper that if you have an operator $T$ which sends soundly the Hardy Space $H^1$ into $L^1$ and also roundly $L^{\infty}$ into $BMO$, then by interpolation result $T$ is bounded in $L^p$ into itself. Do you know the name of this Theorem? I know

I know about the Marcinkiewicz interpolation theorem, but it works with "weak boundless" instead of the spaces $H^1$ and $BMO$.

Thank you very much

Comment: What do "soundly" and "roundly" mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the abstract Riesz-Thorin interpolation theorem. It states that if $(X_0,X_1)$, $(Y_0,Y_1)$ are interpolation couples and $T$ maps $X_j$ continuously into $Y_j$, $j\in\{0,1\}$, then $T$ maps $(X_0,X_1)_\theta$ continuously into $(Y_0,Y_1)_\theta$. In this case, the complex interpolation spaces are $(H^1,L^\infty)_\theta=L^p$ and $(L^1,\mathrm{BMO})_\theta=L^p$ with $\frac 1 p=1-\theta$ (see Janson, Jones. *Interpolation between $H^p$ Spaces: The Complex Method*).

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: And another question, in order to get an estimate of the constant, by this paper "A. P. CALDERÓN, Intermediate spaces and interpolation, the complex method", I also understand that if $||T f||_{Y_j}\leq C_j ||f||_{X_j}$, then I will have (in my case), $||T||_p\leq C_0^{1/p}C_1^{(p-1)/p}$. Am I right?

Comment: @micabua Yes, this is correct.